# readiness probe fails with connection refused

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to setup K8S to work with two Windows Nodes (2019). Everything seems to be working well and the containers are working and accessible using k8s service. But, once I introduce configuration for readiness (or liveness) probes - all fails.  The exact error is:

> Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.1.28:80/test.txt: dial tcp 10.244.1.28:80: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

When I try the url from k8s **master**, it works well and I get 200. However I read that the kubelet is the one executing the probe and indeed when trying from the Windows Node - it cannot be reached (which seems weird because the container is running on that same node). Therefore I assume that the problem is related to some network configuration.

I have a HyperV with External network Virtual Switch configured. K8S is configured to use flannel overlay (vxlan) as instructed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/network-topologies.

Any idea how to troubleshoot and fix this?

**UPDATE**: providing the yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dummywebapplication
  labels:
    app: dummywebapplication
spec:
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: dummywebapplication
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: dummywebapplication
  name: dummywebapplication
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dummywebapplication
      name: dummywebapplication
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dummywebapplication
        image: <my image>
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /test.txt
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 60
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: windows
```

And one more update. In this doc (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/windows/intro-windows-in-kubernetes/) it is written:

> **My Windows node cannot access NodePort service**
>
> Local NodePort access from the node itself fails. This is a known
> limitation. NodePort access works from other nodes or external
> clients.

I don't know if this is related or not as I could not connect to the container from a different node as stated above. I also tried a service of LoadBalancer type but it didn't provide a different result.

Comment: Please provide your actual Deployment (or Pod) yaml, since the details matter _a lot_ in that situation

Comment: It's suspicious that your `Deployment` does not declare any `containerPorts:`; also, it appears that your `Service` is on 80 but is your **container** listening on 80? (I mean, it's a bit of a trick question because the answer is apparently "no")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network configuration assumption was correct. It seems that for 'overlay', by default, the kubelet on the node cannot reach the IP of the container. So it keeps returning timeouts and connection refused messages.

Possible workarounds:

1. Insert an 'exception' into the ExceptionList 'OutBoundNAT' of C:\k\cni\config on the nodes. This is somewhat tricky if you start the node with start.ps1 because it overwrites this file everytime. I had to tweak 'Update-CNIConfig' function in c:\k\helper.psm1 to re-insert the exception similar to the 'l2bridge' in that file.
2. Use '[l2bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/network-topologies#flannel-in-host-gateway-mode)' configuration. Seems like '[overlay](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/windows/#networking)' is running in a more secured isolation, but l2bridge is not.

Comment: Which option did you end up going with in the end @ewolfman? I'm encountering the same problem.

Comment: for the 'overlay' configured cluster i used the first solution and for the l2bridge configured cluster - there was no problem. btw on azure those probes fail too. apparantly this is a known issue with MS and we are going to install a new cluster with the latest Windows nodes where this should be solved.